# Inconsistent data fetch between azure and localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, localhost, azure-virtual-machine

I have a web application which is currently running in a VM on Azure and database for it is mongodB which also runs in a VM. In the application, I have reporting tool to show the data in graphs over any range of dates. I have opted the location of the servers as South India.
My question is that when querying for data over a range of dates, the output is exactly as expected, but when I run the same query in localhost the output is not what it is expected. For example, if I query for 7 days of data I get 6 days data in localhost whereas I get actual 7 days data in Azure.
Any possible solution for this?

Comment: Sorry but "azure in a VM" is not a thing. You possibly mean "Cosmos DB emulator", but I'm also personally getting real tired of repeatedly stating that "Cosmos DB !== MongoDB" and all claims to the contrary are simply untrue.

Comment: @Neil Lunn what I meant to say is that I have web app running in a VM on Azure.

Comment: And you mean to "compared to what". Again **Azure** is NOT a "thing". It's a brand name for a platform. Azure what? Azure VM with MongoDB? Azure VM with CosmosDB? No such thing as "I am using Azure".

Comment: Yes, I running Azure VM with MongoDB.

Comment: And where does the "date" you supply actually come from? Sounds positively hardcoded, or is incorrectly being parsed as UTC when it should in fact be parsed from "local time" and then into UTC by conversion. You need to show some code when asking a question here.